# Statement not checking email value in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am checking if user name and email not exist in database.
it perfectly checking the username but its skipping email i mean not checking email is not exist or not.
This is my db table looks like:
[db table img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oteJ1.jpg)

I tried to put same email in input that exist in db.
what i want is check all rows from email and username and display an error if data already exist.

```
<?php include 'template-parts/header.php'; ?>

  <main class="main-wrap">
<div class="container">
<main class="main-content">
<div class="login-form-wrap">
      <div class="phdr">Registration</div>
      <div class="pad">
        <?php
        include 'config/connection.php';
        if (isset($_POST['regbtn'])) {
          $name = $_POST['regname'];
          $email = $_POST['regemail'];
          $password = $_POST['regpassword'];
          $phone = $_POST['regphone'];

          $mysql = "SELECT * FROM users";
          $myque = mysqli_query($con,$mysql);
          $myres = mysqli_fetch_assoc($myque);
          if ($myres['username'] == $name) { ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
              alert('Username Already Exist!');
            </script>
          <?php }
          if ($myres['useremail'] == $email) { ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
              alert('Email Already Exist!');
            </script>
          <?php }
        }
        ?>
        <form class="#" action="" method="post">
          <p>
            <label for="name"></label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="regname" placeholder="Enter Full Name...">
          </p>
          <p>
            <label for="email"></label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="regemail" placeholder="Enter Email Address...">
          </p>
          <p>
            <label for="password"></label>
            <input type="text" id="password" name="regpassword" placeholder="Enter Password...">
          </p>
          <p>
            <label for="phone"></label>
            <input type="text" id="phone" name="regphone" placeholder="Enter Phone Number...">
          </p>
          <p>
            <input type="submit" name="regbtn" value="Sign Up">
          </p>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Its showing alert if username is exist and not showing alert if email is exist.

Comment: Could you post the (redacted) contents of the `users` table, and your inputs? You are calling `mysqli_fetch_assoc` only once, so you are just checking the first row.

Comment: @Jan Wichelmaan I have updated the code with an img of my db table.hope u understand.tnx

Comment: Do any of the username/email address combinations work?

Comment: i just want to check if user name or email is not exists.if exists show the error.is there any way to check all data of useremail field?

Comment: See my first comment and the answers below. You need to iterate the entire result set, not call `mysqli_fetch_assoc` only once.

Comment: i understand.tnx

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the results, if the email you're checking for is not in the first row of the resultset, your "if ($myres['useremail'] == $email)" will return false.
Alternatively use name and email in the query directly (make sure to escape properly as it comes directly from $_POST!), so you don't need to run through all datasets.

Comment: how can i check all data from that feild "useremail" and "username" in my database and show error if email or username exist?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$myres = mysqli_fetch_assoc($myque)` in a loop because currently name and email just comparing with only first result-set.